# google calendar api update does not update fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-calendar-api, updates

I've used the google calendar api to successfully insert new events.
I'm trying to update events.

I execute the update command and no error is given, but the data on the event does not change. Neither is the 'updated' attribute changed on the event.

The passed data (event['id']) is correct as I have tested it on the google api response headers.

Here is some code (Python):

```
the_event = service.events().get(calendarId='primary', eventId=an_event['id']).execute()

the_event['summary'] = 'im changed'

update_result = service.events().update(calendarId='primary', eventId=the_event['id'], body=the_event)
```

I would appreciate your help